# Cordova plugin-qrscanner no video preview

Tags: android, cordova, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to implemented the cordova QR code reader (https://github.com/bitpay/cordova-plugin-qrscanner ) in my [Quasar](http://quasar-framework.org) app. I copied the example code from the documenation and everything works (preparing, permissions, scan) but the video preview is not showing, I only get a black screen.

The plugin sets the webview to have a transparent background (screen turns black) but the video preview does not apperar. I have tried to manually set all elements (including `<html>` and `<body>`) to either `transparent` or `none` but the screen stays black.

According to the docs, the plugin should add a `<video>` element to the `<body>` but I dont see it. My guess is that Vue removes it in the DOM update. Is that possible? Any ideas?

Comment: Duplicate - I asked exactly the same thing [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43225506/cordova-cordova-plugin-qrscanner-opaque-camera-view) and I still do not have a solution but maybe it will help you somewhat the answer I got. It would be great to find a solution!

Comment: Oops, did not see your post. Just for your information how I solved it: I used the barcode scanner plugin ( https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner ) which can also read QR codes.